# Q:UITableView scrollViewDidScroll function to change the custom navigationBar's alpha

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, alpha

In my `view controller`, I have a `tableView`, and I also add a custom navigationBar on my `view controller`'s view, I want to fade the `alpha` of my custom navigationBar, but its appears no use, and I printed the `alpha` of my custom navigationBar, it shows alright, but my custom navigationBar look like no change on its `alpha`, this is my code:

```
#pragma mark -- scorllView delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == _tableview){

        CGFloat currentOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        // 0 ~ 358  -20 ~ 338
        float alpha_of_scroll = (currentOffsetY + 20) / 358.0;

        NSLog(@"%f", alpha_of_scroll);

        _narBarView.alpha = 1 - alpha_of_scroll;

        NSLog(@"%f", _narBarView.alpha);
    }
}
```

By the way, I have tested use `reactive cocoa`, it shows alike to the `scrollViewDidScroll` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, CGRectGetWidth(self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds) + 20)];
    overlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:overlay atIndex:0];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}


#pragma mark -- scorllView delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(scrollView == self.myTableView){
        CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        NSLog(@"%f", offsetY);
        if (offsetY > -64) {
            if (offsetY >= 0) {
                [self setNavigationBarAlpha:0];
            } else {
                [self setNavigationBarAlpha:(-offsetY / 64)];
            }
        } else {
            [self setNavigationBarAlpha:1];
        }
    }
}

- (void)setNavigationBarAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    [[self.navigationController.navigationBar subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        obj.alpha = alpha;
    }];
}
```

Comment: This method I have found somewhere, but my `navgationBar` is I custom created, which is a` view ` on my `controller's` view.